How to position randomly objects inside box collider area?
after running the game, the objects are not positioned randomly inside the box collider area.
they have positioned randomly but a bit far from the box collider.

this is the results:
i selected all the spawned objects to show where they have been positioned.

the script:
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class FireEffectController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject spawnableItem;
    public BoxCollider area; // Assign the collider of the Fire Collider Area

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        area = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();

        Bounds colliderBounds = area.bounds;
        Vector3 colliderCenter = colliderBounds.center;

        float[] ranges = {
    colliderCenter.x - colliderBounds.extents.x,
    colliderCenter.x + colliderBounds.extents.x,
    colliderCenter.y - colliderBounds.extents.y,
    colliderCenter.y + colliderBounds.extents.y,
};

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            float randomX = Random.Range(ranges[0], ranges[1]);
            float randomY = Random.Range(ranges[2], ranges[3]);

            Vector3 randomPos = new Vector3(randomX, randomY);

            Instantiate(spawnableItem, randomPos, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}


Assuming you actually only want to have random x and y coords and a constant z coord, this script works. In Unity when I assign a spawnableItem, it is indeed spawned 100 times inside the given BoxCollider Volume. Does your spawnableItem prefab maybe have some default offset?

y is the up axis in unity, it should be V3(ranX, y, ranZ).  They all look like they have the random x, but the z is at 0 (which is what your code does).  Change from using the y of the collider, instead use z and assign them like i mentioned ealier.

@anjelomerte the prefab spawnableItem have only particlesystem attached.

Just as a sidenote: why instead of that range not simply use var min = colliderBounds.min; var max = colliderBounds.max; var randomPos = Vector3.zero; randomPos.x = Random.Range(min.x, max.x); randomPos.z = Random.Range(min.z, max.z);
